# Why am I getting a nullptr from my bag file?

Tags: rosbag, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am playing back a bagfile and I get a nullptr when I should be getting actual data.

Below is a screenshot of the bagfile being viewed from RQT. There is only one message called "decomposition/sectors" and I am certain that it should have data. Yet, when I am playing back the bag file in C++ code for a unit test, I get a nullptr for this particular item. Why am I getting this? The other messages will be properly read and instantiated, but not this one.

[image: image description]

Here is a snippet of code which shows how I am reading this:

```
  void CoverageReporterTester::SendMessage(const rosbag::MessageInstance& bag_msg)
  {
    if (topic_name == avidbots_topics::decomposition_sectors)
    {
      message_stack::sector_array msg1 = *bag_msg.instantiate<message_stack::sector_array>();
      SendMessage(topic_name, msg1);
    }
  }

  /* Read bag file */
  rosbag::Bag bag_file;
  std::string bag_dir = ros::package::getPath("coverage_reporter") +
                          "/test/data/bag_files/coverage_reporter.bag";

  bag_file.open(bag_dir, rosbag::bagmode::Read);

  /* List of topics we are interested in */
  std::vector<std::string> topics;
  topics.push_back(topics::decomposition_sectors);

  topics.push_back(avidbots_topics::static_3d_costmap_topic);

  rosbag::View view(bag_file, rosbag::TopicQuery(topics));

  /* Loop through each message in the bag file which is associated with one of our topics listed above */
  foreach(rosbag::MessageInstance const bag_msg, view)
  {
    coverage_reporter.SendMessage(bag_msg);
  }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258362/why-am-i-getting-a-nullptr-from-my-bag-file?/) by [cpagravel](https://answers.ros.org/users/29737/cpagravel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2017-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the answer, the message description had changed since the bagfile was created. If there are any other reasons, please feel free to leave additional answers so others can use this as a reference.

---

Originally posted by [cpagravel](https://answers.ros.org/users/29737/cpagravel/) with karma: 156 on 2017-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-03-31**:
Yep; `instantiate` returns a null pointer if it can't convert the stored message into the type you've given. This can happen if the message definition has changed, or if your code uses the wrong message type.